For a 2D single channel image, what is an appropriate criterion to reorder the rows, such that a JPEG-like encoder performs the best?
I have a huge amount of time series data, each representing some observations at a certain position. Thus of course there exists spatial correlation. I am trying to reorganize these lines of observations to make it as smooth as possible, such that it could be efficiently encoded with an image compressor.
Here the strange thing happens, I reorder these lines with a brute-force algorithm, to minimize the L1-norm between adjcent lines, in a greedy manner, and the 2d "image" does look more smoothier. However, when comes to compression, it performs only slightly better than a random shuffle, and is far worse then the "natural" order, a zig-zag scan of the observed sites.
The compression ratio is (original floating values, ranging from -200 to 200, are enlarged 100 times before converting to integers, they are all encoded with libjxl in loseless mode, the effort level has minor influences):

natural, spatial zig-zag order, 29%
Minimized delta L1-norm, 34%
Random shuffle, 36%

And these are the images:
Manually sorted version, to minimize the delta L1-norm

Natural spatial zig zag order, the image is not that smooth

And this is a comparison between the image gradients (sum of the absolute delta in x and y direction)

I have tried different parameters for the libjxl, and different norms to measure the delta between observation lines. I scrutinized the details of the "2d observation image".

"I am trying to reorganize these lines of observations to make it as smooth as possible, such that it could be efficiently encoded with an image compressor" Why bother with smoothing then? Just use the image format that compresses the type of data you already have, best? Because if you smooth the data, you're literally making it worse to deal with as far as JPEG is concerned: it hates smooth, it wants realistically noisy data. Similarly, smoothing time series data is the best way to make the data useless, the most useful information is in your high frequency variation.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for pointing out that JPEG wants noisy data, is it from the DCT it applied? By the way, I am not smoothing the time series itself, but change their order for storage concern.

The nice thing about "a lot of data" is that it makes compression better, so the real question is "what are you trying to do?". Because if you stick the data in a well optimized image database, good chance it's going to compress better than what you can manually achieve.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have checked again, and found that libjxl uses a prediction/residual-encoding scheme for lossless compression, not the normal domain transform based ones. In this condition, does it still want somehow noise data?

It's still designed around stacked frequency feature compression, just with additional cutting up of your image to it basically creates "multiple jpegs inside a jpeg", so while I'd say "do some benchmarking", I would imagine it does.
